# Haskell concurrency - is forkIO really nondeterministic?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I'm trying to use concurrency in Haskell for a specific optimization in which only one of two values is required, and depending on the situation, either one may be much faster to create than the other.

I thought I could just run 2 threads with forkIO, and then wait until a value is placed in an MVar. Here is a simple Test i have written for this:

```
import Control.Concurrent

main = do out <- newEmptyMVar
          t1 <- forkIO (makeString out)
          t2 <- forkIO (makeInt out)
          v <- takeMVar out
          killThread t1
          killThread t2
          case v of
               Left s -> putStrLn s
               Right i -> putStrLn $ show i

makeString out = do s <- return ( show (primes !! 10000))
                    putMVar out $ Left s

makeInt out = do i <- return 2
                 putMVar out $ Right i

primes = sieve [2..] 
 where sieve (x:xs) = x : (sieve $ filter ((/=0).(flip mod x)) xs)
```

Compiled with:

```
ghc --make -threaded Test
```

However, only the Left s case is ever reached, although getting the prime should take long enough for the makeInt thread to start (and return 2 really shouldn't take that much time). Why is that, and how do I fix this?

Comment: How do you run your code? By default haskell uses light threads rather than real OS threads. I don't know the details, but this may change a lot scheduling policies.

Comment: Might not fit your case, but you might also look into some of the work on "speculative parallelism" being done: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/speculation

Comment: FYI, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-par exposes a rather nice, externally pure parallelism API that nonetheless lets you explicitly state forks, joins, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is laziness. The `makeString` is just inserting a thunk to calculate `show (primes !! 10000)`, which then gets evaluated by the main thread afterwards. Inserting the thunk is quite fast, so it happens to win the race in this case.

To force evaluation to happen within the thread, you can change `return` to `evaluate`:

```
makeString out = do s <- evaluate $ show (primes !! 10000)
                    putMVar out $ Left s
```

This should cause `makeInt` to win the race in most cases (although it's not guaranteed).

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot to account for laziness.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the threads really are non-deterministic (in GHC).

It just happens your particular code is structured and optimized in such a way that t1 always wins. There are no guarantees.

If you want to try to massage it to produce a different outcome, try turning on optimizations (`-O2`) and/or using multiple cores (`+RTS -N`).

E.g. on my machine, two runs in a row:

```
$ ghc -O2 -threaded --make A.hs -rtsopts -fforce-recomp
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, A.o )
Linking A.exe ...
$ ./A +RTS -N2
2
$ ./A +RTS -N2
104743
```

As hammar points out, you can also structure your code to force more work to take place in the thread (or switch to [using strict mvars](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-concurrency)).

Comment: Thank you - I didn't even know I could pass parameters to the RTS.